# Manipulating a struct in an existing variable

Tags: struct, elixir

Complete Elixir beginner. I am sure I am missing some fundamental issues in the following. Can someone please explain, exactly why the second code not work as the first one?

```
defmodule Bulb do
  defstruct [:state]

  def turn_on(bulb = %Bulb{}) do
    %{bulb | state: :on}
  end

  def turn_off(bulb = %Bulb{}) do
    %{bulb | state: :off}
  end
end

bulb = %Bulb{state: :on} # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb |> Bulb.turn_off() # --> %Bulb{state: :off}
bulb |> Bulb.turn_on() # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
```

versus

```
defmodule Bulb do
  defstruct [:state]

  def switch_bulb(bulb = %Bulb{}) do
    case bulb do
      %{state: :off} -> %{bulb | state: :on}
      %{state: :on} -> %{bulb | state: :off}
    end
  end
end

bulb = %Bulb{state: :on} # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :off}
bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :off} why?
```

(Yes, the second one also works if I do the following.)

```
defmodule Bulb do
  defstruct [:state]

  def switch_bulb(bulb = %Bulb{}) do
    case bulb do
      %{state: :off} -> %{bulb | state: :on}
      %{state: :on} -> %{bulb | state: :off}
    end
  end
end

bulb = %Bulb{state: :on} # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb = bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :off}
bulb = bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), everything is immutable. `bulb |> Bulb.turn_on()` from the first snippet does not do what you think it does. It does literally nothing, actually, “switching” the state from `on` (initial value) to `on`.

To understand, what happens, do print `bulb` every time.

```elixir
bulb = %Bulb{state: :on} # %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb |> IO.inspect() |> Bulb.turn_off() |> IO.inspect() # on → off
bulb |> IO.inspect() |> Bulb.turn_on() |> IO.inspect() # on → on
```

`bulb` from inside `switch_bulb/1` function has the same name, but a very different scope, it’s not the same variable. `bulb` stays what it was assigned to.

```elixir
bulb = %Bulb{state: :on}   # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
IO.inspect(bulb)           # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :off}
bulb                       # --> %Bulb{state: :on}
bulb |> Bulb.switch_bulb() # --> %Bulb{state: :off} why?
```

Even more: the example below *won’t change the value of outermost `bulb` too*

```elixir
bulb = :on
if true, do: bulb = :off # different scope, outermost `bulb` is untouched
IO.inspect(bulb) #⇒ :on
```

That said unless you reassign the value of *any* expression, it simply gets lost. Nothing is mutated in place.

---

BTW, `=` is NOT an assignment, it’s a matching operator. In this case, it’s *rebinding* the variable.